# Unable to Deploy Kubernetes Federation on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to setup Kubernetes Federation on GKE following the instructions in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/federation/set-up-cluster-federation-kubefed/. The Kubernetes version in my nodes is `v1.9.7-gke.6`. I ran the command `kubefed init federation1 --host-cluster-context=[CONTEXT] --dns-provider="google-clouddns" --dns-zone-name=[DNS_ZONE]`. This would stay at `Waiting for federation control plane to come up........` forever.

Checking the status of the apiserver pod I saw this error message:

`Failed to pull image "gcr.io/k8s-jkns-e2e-gce-federation/fcp-amd64:v1.10.0-alpha.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/k8s-jkns-e2e-gce-federation/fcp-amd64/manifests/v1.10.0-alpha.0: denied: Token exchange failed for project 'k8s-jkns-e2e-gce-federation'. Please enable or contact project owners to enable the Google Container Registry API in Cloud Console at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/containerregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=k8s-jkns-e2e-gce-federation before performing this operation.`

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to access an API, which must be enabled first.
Can you check if this is as follows:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, Google Container Registry API is already enabled for my project. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: what is your google cloud project name, is it k8s-jkns-e2e-gce-federation ?

Comment: No, my project name is `My First Project`

Comment: That is the problem, you are trying to access the resources for k8s-jkns-e2e-gce-federation, when your project name is something else. Its like trying to access the house of your neighbor with the key from yours. Both are houses, but the key (token in this case), are different.